# How to remove the protrude of the path with arrow?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-styles

From this code is from an answer to my previous post. The arrow is nice but if I want to move the arrow to the end of the path by setting `mark = at position 1` there is still a protrude part which doesn't look nice.

Is there any idea to remove this part?

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone} 
\usepackage[american, siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings, arrows.meta} 
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\ctikzset{inductors/scale=0.5, capacitors/scale=0.5, sources/scale=0.5, switches/scale=0.5}
\draw  (0,0) coordinate (start)  node[ocirc]{} to [cute open switch]
++(1,0)  to [cute inductor, l^=$L$] ++(1,0) to [short]++(0.5,0) node[ocirc]{} coordinate (end);
\begin{scope}[on background layer, decoration={
markings, mark=at position 1 with {\arrow{Stealth[scale=0.8]}}} ]  
\draw[ultra thick, red!40, postaction={decorate}, transform canvas={yshift=3pt}] (start) --(end);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you need a decoration for that? Just do `-{Stealth[scale=0.8]}` at that path and PGF/TikZ will handle the tip correctly.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel sorry where should I add that in the code?

Comment: `\begin{scope}[on background layer]\draw[ultra thick, red!40, -{Stealth[scale=0.8]}, transform canvas={yshift=3pt}] (start) -- (end);\end{scope}`. No need for the decoration if you want to just use an arrow tip at the end of a line, [that's the original usecase](https://tikz.dev/tikz-arrows#sec-16.1). The `markings` decoration is only needed if you need an arrow tip somewhere else.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel that is nice. It would be best if you put that as an answer so we can refer it later (although it would be great if decoration works as well).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normal arrow:

```
\draw[-{Stealth[scale=0.8]}, ultra thick, red!40, transform canvas={yshift=3pt}] (start) -- (end);
```

If you for some reason need to do it with a decoration, you need to manually shorten the line like this:

```
\draw[ultra thick, red!40, postaction={decorate}, transform canvas={yshift=3pt}, shorten >=2pt] (start) --(end);
```

[image: Circuit with red arrow behind]

Comment: It's nice to know `shorten`.

Comment: Notice that the option is *not* `shorten` but `shorten >` (or `shorten <` for the other end).